# What is the best practice to use jQuery with a Java web app

Tags: java, jquery

I want to know what is the best practice to develop a jQuery web app with java in the back end. Should generate my response in a servlet, using a jsf facelet, a normal jsp, with XML, spring mvc? What is the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of different ways to do this, and which is "best" is a subjective question.

Comment: Okay, i will ask my question in a subjective Forum.

Answer (score 1):

Subjectively speaking,
We use a servlet which returns xml, and that has been working nicely. It is easy to handle the response using `jQuery.parseXML();`

Comment: Any reason to avoid the other options stated by the asker, or it's just personal preference? Stating your personal preference is not very useful on a site based on facts. Note that I did vote to close the question.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I would say that xml is easy to deal with, but that could be said about the other options. Considering we don't know anything about the project, I suspect all the answers will be personal preferences.

Comment: If no better answer than personal preference can be made, perhaps it shouldn't be answered at all

Comment: Well, I feel that open-ended questions should be respected more than they are on SO, so that's why I answered.

Comment: Answers on stack overflow should be based on facts, not opinions. That's why such open-ended questions don't really belong here.

Comment: Well, it's not closed yet. Besides, all the time in programming you have to decide what is the best way to do something, so a persons opinion of what is a better answer is quite relevant on SO.

Comment: I really don't know where SO is moving (subjective answers are really no good for a site like this), but: The process of closing is getting really inefficient, and: questions like these used to be allowed on stack overflow. They were closed later on. I'm not convinced we should get back to these.

Comment: Yeah, I mean this question is REALLY vague, and should be closed I think, but I have seen better subjective questions with more detail get downvoted to oblivion, which I have found unfortunate at times.

Comment: I guess it's mostly based on when you start downvoting. Downvotes attract attention. Perhaps I should have.